# Add click event to appended item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, append

I am trying to add a `click` event to an element that I appended through jQuery.
If I have the item in my HTML code the `click` event works fine. I hope the code explains it better

**HTML**

```
<div id="addNew">Add new Item</div>
<div id="priceWrapper"></div>
<div class="price"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var data;
$('#addNew').click(function () {
    $('#priceWrapper').append('<div class="item" data-js="2.5" id="Item" >(I dont work i was not here on load)I AM AN ITEM WICH COSTS 2.5€</div>');
});
$('#Item').click(function () {
    data = $(this).attr("data-js");
    alert(data);
});
```

Example in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwgenvnn/)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Ah search like a full day on here how could i not find this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery **`.on`**. More information [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
var data;
$('#addNew').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#priceWrapper').append('<div class="item" data-js="2.5" id="Item" style="background-color:yellow;border-bottom:solid 5px green">(I dont work i was not here on load)I AM AN ITEM WICH COSTS 2.5€</div>');
});

$('body').on('click', '.item', function () {
    data = $(this).attr("data-js");
    alert(data);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/mwgenvnn/3/)

---

The reason this doesn't work is because first of all, **only *one*** element can have an `id` at a time. We have to set it to use the *class* `.item`. The other problem is the event is getting set **when the page loads** so it doesn't notice the new items.